# High Memory Usage When Downloading Azure Blob through WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using the DownloadToStreamEncrypted extension from https://github.com/stefangordon/azure-encryption-extensions and it works fine for small files. I've noticed that it loads the entire stream into memory however.
I am using ASP.Net WebAPI. Here is my code:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();

await blob.DownloadToStreamEncryptedAsync(provider, stream);

stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;

response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = docLength;
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(doc.MimeType);
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = "somefilename",
    Size = docLength
};
return response;
```

This works, but the memory used goes up by however big the file is. It doesn't actually stream the file back. Is there something I am doing wrong with the stream that is causing this high memory use? Ideally, it just streams back from the server without first getting loaded into memory in its entirety. I suspect the problem is the CopyToAsync method within the DownloadToStreamEncrypted but am not sure.

The code for DownloadToStreamEncrypted is

```
using (Stream blobStream = await blob.OpenReadAsync(accessCondition, options, operationContext))
            using (Stream decryptedStream = provider.DecryptedStream(blobStream))
            {
                await decryptedStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
```

Is there something I can do to lower the memory usage?

Comment: In you code, the variable 'stream' is not disposed after using, should it be?

Comment: No, WebAPI does that for me through the StreamContent

Comment: Try this tool: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924.

Comment: I can try that, but the problem is that the entire stream is getting read into memory before downloading. It isn't a memory leak--just me not handling the stream properly.

Comment: If I just use Stream blobStream = await blob.OpenReadAsync(accessCondition, options, operationContext) and then pass that stream to the StreamContent, the file will download with low memory usage. I can't do that because I need to decrypt